# How to Show/Hide/Toggle Element with ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

How to Show/Hide/Toggle Element with ExtJS?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Very straightforward, at the element level (further to the comments below):

```
Ext.get("my-div");
```

Where `my-div` is the id of the element in question.

See [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element) and [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.html#method-Ext.Element-get)

At the component level:

```
Ext.getCmp('idofthecomponent').getEl().show();
Ext.getCmp('idofthecomponent').getEl().hide();
Ext.getCmp('idofthecomponent').getEl().toggle();
```

See [here (show)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.fx.html#method-Ext.Element-show), [here (hide)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.fx.html#method-Ext.Element-hide) and [here (toggle)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.fx.html#method-Ext.Element-toggle) respectively. So 'idofthecomponent' would be, say the id assigned to a Panel object.

You can also refer to the element directly using other selectors, such as [document.getElementbyId](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php), eg.

```
 document.getElementById('elementtoshow').show();
```

Comment: FYI, get() should be used in favor of getEl() which is deprecated. Note that getEl() is not listed in the docs.

Comment: that is not correct - getEl IS listed in the docs, goto http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/ and type 'getEl'. It is not deprecated for use at the component level, in that context 'get' returns an underlying component, NOT the wrapping element as required here (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Container.html#method-Ext.Container-get) vs (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Component.html#method-Ext.Component-getEl).

Comment: Ergo, Brian is correct about get/getEl in this case. Your doc references are to Container and Component which are different from an Element in Ext JS.

Comment: Valid- ammended the question as noted

Comment: Thanks, learned a lot from your site while I was getting to grips with ExtJs in the first place :)

Answer (score 5):

Ext.AbstractComponent has a hidden property which you can set as true in initialization and then alter programatically on demand

```
items: [{
     xtype: 'button',
     itemId: 'submitButton',
     text: 'Submit',
     hidden: true
}]
```

and then later...

```
me.getComponent('submitButton').hidden = false;
```