# Extjs proper way to show/hide

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm a little new to Extjs and I'm trying to figure out the proper way to show/hide elements.

I have the following elements:

```
layout: 'card',
items: 
[
 {
  xtype: 'Panel1'
 },
 {
  xtype: 'Panel2'
 }
]
```

In my controller I have these references setup:

```
refs: [
{
 ref: 'p1',
 selector: 'Panel1'
},
{
 ref: 'p2',
 selector: 'Panel2'
}
],
```

Each panel has a form and two buttons at the bottom.  Panel 2 is hidden in the beginning.  Now I want to show Panel 2 and hide Panel 1.  First I tried:

```
this.getp1().hide();
this.getp2().show();
```

...and that did nothing.  Then, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074673/how-to-show-hide-toggle-element-with-extjs) and tried out the following:

```
this.getp1().getEl().hide();
this.getp2().getEl().show();
```

which partially worked except that it failed to also show the buttons in Panel2.  Am I supposed to get every single element and `show()` each of them?  I must be missing something.

Comment: No, you should most definitely be showing/hiding the component. There's not enough information.

Comment: What extra information is needed?

Comment: A working example, you can't just post small snippets like that.

Comment: Sure enough, there was more to it than just this.  It turns out that I was putting those elements into a container that had `layout:'card'`.  Once I commented out that layout, it worked - and once I figured out how to setActiveItem on a card it worked even better.  I edited my question and I'll let you answer it if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent panel of my two problem items was of a `layout: 'card'`.  According to the [sencha docs on the Card layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Card) only one panel will be shown at a time.  Therefore, the proper way to show other items is not via the show/hide function, but rather calling 
`PARENT_PANEL.getLayout().setActiveItem(n);`  That was causing my p2 panel to always be hidden and not affected by the `show()` method.

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
this.getP1().hide(); //the first letter should be uppercase
this.getP2().show();
```